# Can I write a CSS selector for a div NOT containing a link

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm having a piece of html code that's generated so it's not really possible to alter. It has 2 variants that are both used multiple times on a page.
Variant 1:

```
<figure class="image">
  <img src="...something.jpg" />
</figure>
```

and variant 2:

```
<figure class="image">
  <a href="...something.nl">
     <img src="...something.jpg" />
  </a>
</figure>
```

**Is there a way to select the 'image' class only in the first example?** So only if it doesn't contain the link tag? Because if the figure does contain a link I don't want to target the figure itself but the link tag it contains.

Reason I'm asking is because I added a color overlay using a pseudo element on the image class.

```
.image { position: relative; }
.image:after { content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; opacity: 0.40; background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(36, 161, 218, 1) 82%); mix-blend-mode: exclusion; }
```

That works great in the first variant, but it's blocking the link in the second variant, so the image is not clickable. So in the second example i'd like to add the pseudo element to the 'a' instead of to the 'image' class. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You mean check if `img` is a direct descendant of `.image` class? Like so: `.image > img`? See [Child combinators on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)

Comment: your are overcomplicating it, add `pointer-events:none` to the pseudo element and it's done

Comment: @TemaniAfif Adding that did the trick indeed :-) thanx! And for Roy's comment, yes I did like to target the .image class figure if img is a direct descendant. In your example I would be tageting the img instead right?